# Can I Use 2 Model Attributes Annotations in One Controller Method?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC. I have a Controller Method was written and has a model attribute annotation already in it, I need to bind a second form to the same controller, so I can get other information passed to it.

Am I allowed to that or will it cause conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I can. I was getting null values from the form, when it was pulling. I thought that might be the problem. It  was not.